# Find the number of subsequences of a n-digit number, that are divisible by 8

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given n = 1 to 10^5, stored as a string in decimal format.

Example: If n = 968, then out of all subsequences i.e 9, 6, 8, 96, 68, 98, 968 there are 3 sub-sequences of it, i.e 968, 96 and 8, that are divisible by 8. So, the answer is 3.

Since the answer can be very large, print the answer modulo (10^9 + 7).

Comment: What have you tried so far? It has a dynamic programming tag. Do you have ideas about what the state and the transition could be?

Comment: If the string is `88`, what is the answer? Is it 3 (8, 8 again and 88) or 2 (counting 8 only once)?

Comment: Are they really [subsequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence), or substrings? There can be `2^(10^5)` subsequences, that's quite a lot...

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Where do you get that from?  Most numbers under 10^5 are 4 digits long, so there are only 2^4 subsequences.  Which isn't so many.

Comment: @btilly the title says it's an n-digit number where n can be up to 100000, right?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Wow.  You're right.  That will be a large number.  But nothing that your average big integer library will have trouble with.

Comment: @kraskevich, If the string is 88, answer is 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic programming. Let `f(len, sum)` be the number of subsequences of the prefix of length `len` such that their sum is `sum` modulo 8 (`sum` ranges from 0 to 7).

The value of `f` for `len = 1` is obvious. The transitions go as follows:

1. We can start a new subsequence in the new position: `f(len, a[i] % 8) += 1`.
2. We can continue any subsequence from the shorter prefix:

   ```
   for old_sum = 0..7
        f(len, (old_sum * 10 + a[i]) % 8) += f(len - 1, old_sum) // take the new element
        f(len, old_sum) += f(len - 1, old_sum) // ignore the new element
   ```

Of course, you can perform all computations module 10^9 + 7 and use a standard integer type.

3. The answer is `f(n, 0)` (all elements are taken into account and the sum modulo 8 is 0).

The time complexity of this solution is `O(n)` (as there are `O(n)` states and 2 transition from each of them).

Note: if the numbers can't have leading zeros, you can just one more parameter to the state: a flag that indicates whether the first element of the subsequence is zero (this sequences should never be extended). The rest of the solution stays the same.

Comment: This would be the proper solution for subsequences rather than substrings +1

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answer assumes you mean contiguous subsequences.

The divisibility rule for a number to be divisible by `8` is if the last three digits of the number are divisible by 8. Using this, a simple `O(n)` algorithm can be obtained where `n` is the number of digits in the number.

1. Let `N=a_0a_1...a_(n-1)` be the decimal representation of `N` with `n` digits.
2. Let the number of sequences so far be `s = 0`
3. For each set of three digits, `a_i a_(i+1) a_(i+2)`, check if the number is divisible by `8`. If so, add `i + 1` to the number of sequences, i.e., `s = s + i`. This is because all strings `a_k..a_(i+2)` will be divisible by `8` for `k` ranging from `0..i`.
4. Loop `i` from `0` to `n-2-1` and continue.

So, if you have `1424968`, the subsequences divisible are at:

1. `i=1` (`424` yielding `i+1 = 2` numbers: `424` and `1424`)
2. `i=3` (`496` yielding `i+1 = 4` numbers: `496`, `2496`, `42496`, `142496`)
3. `i=4` (`968` yielding `i+1 = 5` numbers: `968`, `4968`, `24968`, `424968`, `1424968`)

Note that some small modifications will be needed to consider numbers lesser than three digits in length.

Hence the total number of sequences = `2 + 4 + 5 = 11`. Total complexity = `O(n)` where `n` is the number of digits.

Comment: Yes, exploiting the divisibility rule makes this much easier than any "naive" approach of checking individual subsequences would be

Answer (score 0):

There are 10 possible states a subsequence can be in.  The first is empty.  The second is that there was a leading 0.  And the other 8 are a ongoing number that is 0-7 mod 8.  You start at the beginning of the string with 1 way of being empty, no way to be anything else.  At the end of the string your answer is the number of ways to have a leading 0 plus an ongoing number that is 0 mod 8.

The transition table should be obvious.  The rest is just normal dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the fact that for any three-digit number `abc` the following holds:

```
abc % 8 = ((ab % 8) * 10 + c) % 8
```

Or in other words: the test for a number with a fixed start-index can be cascaded:

```
int div8(String s){
    int total = 0, mod = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        mod = (mod * 10 + s.charAt(i) - '0') % 8

        if(mod == 0)
            total++;
    }

    return total;
}
```

But we don't have fixed start-indices!
Well, that's pretty easy to fix:

Suppose two sequences `a` and `b`, such that `int(a) % 8 = int(b) % 8` and `b` is a suffix of `a`. No matter what how the sequence continues, the modulos of `a` and `b` will always remain equal. Thus it's sufficient to keep track of the number of sequences that share the property of having an equal value modulo 8.

```
final int RESULTMOD = 1000000000 + 7;

int div8(String s){
    int total = 0;
    //modtable[i] is the number of subsequences with int(sequence) % 8 = i
    int[] modTable = new int[8];

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        int[] nextTable = new int[8];

        //transform table from last loop-run (shared modulo)
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            nextTable[(j * 10 + s.charAt(i) - '0') % 8] = modTable[j] % RESULTMOD;
        }

        //add the sequence that starts at this index to the appropriate bucket
        nextTable[(s.charAt(i) - '0') % 8]++;

        //add the count of all sequences with int(sequence) % 8 = 0 to the result
        total += nextTable[0];
        total %= RESULTMOD;

        //table for next run
        modTable = nextTable;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Runtime is `O(n)`.